# PDO error when trying to insert to iSeries DB2 with php on Linux

Tags: php, linux, pdo, odbc, ibm-midrange

I've been having issues trying to run an insert statement via php to the iSeries DB2 via PDO odbc.

The following is my php script:

```
<?php

$empl_number  = $argv[1];
$empl_estatus = $argv[2];
$empl_lname   = $argv[3];
$empl_fname   = $argv[4];
$empl_user    = $argv[5];

try {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `USER_PROFILE_AD` (`EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`, `EMPLOYEE_STATUS`, `LAST_NAME`, `FIRST_NAME`, `LDAP_RDN`, `ACTIVE`, `USER_PROFILE`) VALUES (:numb, :stat, :lname, :fname, :usern, :active, :profile)";
    $conn = new PDO("odbc:AS400TST");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':numb', $empl_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':stat', $empl_estatus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $empl_lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $empl_fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usern', $empl_user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':active', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':profile', NULL, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
    $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

When I run the script via command line...

```
user@server: /usr/bin/php myscript.php 1234 AC DOE JOHN JOHN.DOE
```

I get the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 0 [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Statement violates access rule: Connection is set to read only. (SQLPrepare[0] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.4.16/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:206)
```

I double-checked with the iSeries developer and the username that I using DOES have fully access to the database/table/etc...

Would you please help me to see why the insert doesn't work?

NOTES:

- Connection works fine.
- "Select" statements works just fine.
- at /etc/odbc.ini, the CommitMode = 2

Thanks in advance,

EGMWEB

Answer (score 0):

From my research, this error is commonly caused by an upgrade or PTF applied to the IBM i OS. The fix is to obtain a current ODBC driver. Your administrator should be able to help with this.

Comment: jmarkmurphy, thanks for your reply. I'll check with our iSeries Admin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution -

For your reference in case some one else is having this issue...

The following article: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzatv/rzatvodbcman.htm

Explains the settings to be done at the odbc.ini

...

```
DefaultLibraries = QGPL
Database =
ConnectionType = 0
CommitMode = 2
ExtendedDynamic = 0
DefaultPkgLibrary = QGPL
DefaultPackage = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression = 1
LibraryView = 0
AllowUnsupportedChar = 0
ForceTranslation = 0
Trace = 0
```

...
Remember to change "QGPL" on both params for yours

I adjusted the parameters and I got it to work.

Thank you all!!

EGMWEB

Answer (score 0):

The table is not journaled if selects work.  You'll have to start journaling of the table for add change delete to work.  ACD doesn't work.

on the as400.

STRJRNPF  ...